# When calling wininet functions random NullReferenceException occur

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke, wininet

Not sure why but at random when calling the function `InternetQueryDataAvailable` a null ref exception occurs for no apparent reason sins non of the arguments which it accepts can be null:

```
[DllImport(Dlls.Wininet, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool InternetQueryDataAvailable([In] IntPtr hFile, [Out] out int numberOfBytesAvailable, [Optional, In] int reserved0, [Optional, In] IntPtr reserved1);
```

Here is the exception:

[image]

And no, `CheckHandle()` isn't the culprit as all it does is check if `_handle` is zero or not, aka invalid.

Also, if not this then after downloading all the data and attempting to close the application, sins I set it up so all the handles close before the app closes, the call to `InternetCloseHandle` throws the null ref exception even tho, just like with `InternetQueryDataAvailable`, non of the arguments are nullable sins all it accepts is a single `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport(Dlls.Wininet, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool InternetCloseHandle([In] IntPtr hInternet);
```

Am not sure what's going on because, on rare occasions everything works fine and I am able to download all the data and close the handle without a random exception being thrown.

For those wondering what the function with InternetCloseHandle looks like, it's just:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        if (!WinINet.InternetCloseHandle(_handle))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        _handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

}
```

Note that the exception which is thrown after calling `InternetQueryDataAvailable` only occurs after the first call, so the first is fine but all the ones after have a chance of triggering the exception.

Comment: I would guess that means that _handle is not set. But it would help a ton if you showed the inner exception and stacktrace - basically the result of Exception.ToString(). There are two articles on Exception handling that I do link often, it might be worth a read for you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Christopher `_handle` is `IntPtr`, even if it were zero, 1) A custom exception would be thrown due to CheckHandle, 2) A null ref exception wouldn't be possible sins `IntPtr` isn't nullable, and even if the issue were with `_handle` which it isn't, sins it points to a valid http request data file, `InternetQueryDataAvailable` returns a boolean which indicates if it successfully completed or not and shouldn't throw exceptions, especially not managed c# ones.

Comment: But what if the value of InPtr is null? I am a bit rusty, but IIRC a pointer set to all "0" is the non-reference way of anotating null values.
Would a try to resolve the instance behind _handle then not throw a null reference Exception?

Comment: The NullReferenceException could be coming from InternetQueryDataAvailable itself, perhaps because the handle is non-null but invalid.

Comment: @RaymondChen as I wrote: `Note that the exception which is thrown after calling InternetQueryDataAvailable only occurs after the first call`, the first call succeeds, and no I don't call `InternetCloseHandle` right after, after it I call `InternetReadFile` which then loops back to `InternetQueryDataAvailable` this goes on until either the return from the query is false or the number of bytes is zero, only after that is the handle closed, so no, the handle is valid throughout the entire procedure.

Comment: Remove Optional attributes and pass something real

Comment: @SimonMourier tried it, removed Optional and did `InternetQueryDataAvailable(_handle, out numberOfBytes, 0, IntPtr.Zero);`, but it didn't change anything, null ref exception still occurs.

Comment: Okay, but my point is that the NullReferenceException may be coming from InternetQueryDataAvailable itself. Don't rule that out. Running with a debugger on first-chance exceptions should identify the source.

Comment: @RaymondChen seams like it, well, the conclusion I came to is that I was spending to much time downloading the data because it expired and that's why the exception was thrown, not to sure but it seamed to have solved the issue for me for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thing I didn't point out, which was the cause of this null ref exception, was that when `InternetOpen` is performed, I instantly assign the handle to a status callback via `InternetSetStatusCallback` by just doing `InternetSetStatusCallback(handle, CallbackMethod);`, apparently what was happening was that the GC collected the delegate because it supposedly wasn't being used, note that when `InternetQueryDataAvailable` is called the statuses `INTERNET_STATUS_RECEIVING_RESPONSE` and `INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED` do get passed to the callback, so am not sure why the GC collected the delegate but, that was the cause of the null ref. It wasn't that the `InternetQueryDataAvailable` was throwing the exception, as some suspected.
The solution for this was to create a field to which the delegate is assigned, like that the GC wont collect it due to the fact that the class housing it is always alive and is never out of scope.

Comment: If you feel like down voting this answer then please, either provide a better answer or comment why you have decided to down vote. Note that commenting something like: `This is not a good answer, but I don't have a answer of my own` isn't a good excuse.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that the exception which is thrown after calling InternetQueryDataAvailable only occurs after the first call, so the first is fine but all the ones after have a chance of triggering the exception.

This is to be expected. It is a data retreival. Those can *always* run into Exogenous Exceptions. It does not mater if that function wraps around a file access or a network operation going over half the planet - both of those scenarios got exogenous exception potential in spades.

Of course the specific exception is still odd.

Comment: True but, as written in the doc for `InternetQueryDataAvailable`: `If there is currently no data available and the end of the file has not been reached, the request waits until data becomes available.`. Also, unmanaged code can not throw managed exceptions, the only thing that can is COM imported stuff and still, only of type `ComException`.

Comment: @VincentBree: Even when it waits, it should only wait until timeout happens or it is confirmed the connection is broken. Still waiting then rather then ending with exception in those cases would be a bad idea. Poor handling of explosives bad, in fact :)